# Importing GeoPackage via GeoPackage vs. Import Vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, import, geopackage

Is there any difference when importing a GeoPackage into QGIS using the data source manager between using the section `"Vector"` and the section `"GeoPackage"`?

I did not see any difference so far, but this may be because my geopackages are rather simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a GeoPackage file, you can store different data like vectors, raster data, even styling data and whole QGIS projects. So using the `"GeoPackage"` tab in the source manager allows you to inspect the different type of data and load vectors as well as rasters. Whereas using the `"Vector"` tab allows you to load the containing vector data as layers.